# HTML Contact Form Formats Email Strangely

Tags: html

I'm making a contact form that a user can type in then when they click submit it opens Outlook with their input. The problem is that the output is really messy. It outputs like this:

```
name=John+Smith&email=I+am+contacting+you&comment=example+text+here
```

I want to output to be more like:

```
name=John Smith  email=I am contacting you comment=example text here
```

Is that possible with this HTML5 code:

```
 <form method="post" name="contact" action="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">          
                <p>         
                <label>Name</label>
                <input name="name" value="Your Name" input type="text" size="50" />
                <label>Email</label>
                <input name="email" value="Your Email" input type="text" size="50" />
                <label>Your Comments</label>
                <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="comment"></textarea>
                <br />  
                <input class="button" input type="submit" />        
                </p>        
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not specified otherwise, your form is “send” using the default enctype `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Add the attribute `enctype="text/plain"` to your form element.